# how to pass vectors of word to LSTM?

Tags: lstm, word2vec

Im working on sentiment analysis using LSTM,
I have a dataset in csv format with ['Sentiment', 'Tweet'].
Wor2vec model is trained on this dataset, but now i dont know how to feed this as input to lstm. I've tried replacing the words in csv file with vectors, but i could't do it. 
Is there any look up method need to be used while building lstm or 
we have to replace words in csv file with vectors, but how to do it ?

(i have saved my trained word2vec model)

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using? In any case, yes, you would have to map each unit of input (each data point) to word IDs. For example, if the following is a single tweet that you want to feed to your model:

fox jumps over the brown dog

this will be converted via a dictionary to an input comprised entirely of word IDs (with some padding based on how your LSTM is designed)

23 69 10 4 254 145

these numbers can be stored in a numpy array, e.g., before you feed them to the network and give the sentiment (lets' say 0.54) as the expected output.